# Rounding Using Set Numbers

Tags: excel

I have a list of cable measurements which range from 40 - 500.
I'm looking for it to round up to the nearest option (40, 60, 80, 120, 300, 500 as these are the cable lengths available)
But with a variable of rounding up or down by 10.

So if the measurement is 121, I want it to round down to 120.
if its 131, i want it to round up to 300.

Am i asking too much?

Comment: Have a look at [`XMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12406049?hl=en-GB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give a try on the following formula-

```
=LET(x,XLOOKUP(A2,{40,60,80,120,300,500},{40,60,80,120,300,500},0,-1),IF((A2-x)<10,x,XLOOKUP(A2,{40,60,80,120,300,500},{40,60,80,120,300,500},0,1)))
```

[image]

Comment: You are a gem, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to know! If it helps then please consider accepting the answer (tick mark it). [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)